# Expects a string, array given functions.wp-scripts.php

Tags: php, wordpress

I get this warning and need to track down why $handle is an array or where it is.

> [08-Jan-2019 19:13:46 UTC] PHP Warning:  explode()
>   expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in
>   /web/content/wp-includes/functions.wp-scripts.php on line 297

I am having trouble finding what is causing the warning. Any advice as to how is appreciated.

I checked all `enqueue_script` in `functions.php`. Warning says second parameter which is `src` has the error.

```
if ( $src || $in_footer ) {
    $_handle = explode( '?', $handle );

    if ( $src ) {
        $wp_scripts->add( $_handle[0], $src, $deps, $ver );
    }

    if ( $in_footer ) {
        $wp_scripts->add_data( $_handle[0], 'group', 1 );
    }
}
```

Comment: _"explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given"_ This is pretty self-explanatory. `$handle` is an array, but should be a string. If you're asking why is `$handle` an array, we can't deduce that from this code.

Comment: How can I go about finding out why $handle is an array? Are there tools out there? Do I check each line of hundreds of files? Like I said, I am having trouble finding WHAT is CAUSING the warning. Any advice how to track it down?

Comment: var dump is NULL, i'll look for $handle

Comment: `if(is_array($handle)){explode()}....` Will check if $handle is an array and only then try to explode